# Is there any way to add class to input using FluentBootstrap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentbootstrap

`@form.EditorFor().AddAttributes(new {@class="class"})` makes a div wrapper with added attributes, is there any way to actually add class to input itself instead of wrapping it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took so long for me to find this - still not used to coming on StackOverflow and searching for my libs :).

Unfortunately, you can't do what you want to at this time. As far as I know, you wouldn't be able to do it in straight ASP.NET MVC either.

The problem is that calling `EditorFor()` really just farms out to an editor template (Scott Hanselman has a nice little [real-world example on his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx)). Depending on the model property type, the editor template could have an `<input>`, or it could have a `<textarea>`, or it could have a whole bunch of form elements for a really complex editing experience. Since we don't know what the `EditorFor()` might return, we have no way of knowing to which element, or even if, the extra attributes should be applied.